# How to create a std::array wrapper class

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, stl, stdarray

Background:

I'm trying to create a few of my own wrapper classes for the STL containers so I can separate implementation from my code base. I have already done alittle bit with my Vector class wrapper like so:

Vector.h

```
template<typename type>
    class Vector
    {
    public:
        Vector();
        Vector(std::initializer_list<type> initializer);
        Vector(int size, int defaultValue);
        Vector(int size);
        ~Vector();

        void PushBack(type itemToPushBack);
        type AtPosition(int position);

    private:
        std::vector<type> m_collectionOfItems;
    };
```

As you can see, I have constructors setup and I've used `std::vector` as a member so that I can just call std::vector functions within my own Vector classes.

Issue:

With `std::array` I have to specificy a size immediately when instantiating any object. So if I created a member variable like I did with my vector class, I would have to give that array object a size. I would rather the size be specified by the user using some similar constructor setup to Vector's (ex. MyArrayClass myArray(10) ). How might I try and implement this Array wrapper?

Comment: `std::array` wraps a static array, so its size must be specified at compile-time. A `std::vector` is an array whose size is determined dynamically at run-time.

Comment: The whole point of `std::array`, its chief distinction from `std::vector`, is that its size is determined at compile time and thus it doesn't require a dynamic memory allocation. If you insist on wrapping `std::array`, your wrapper should have the same property, otherwise it would largely defeat the point.

Comment: The standard containers are already designed to be as interchangeable as possible. Your time may be better served learning what generic functions are available to make container code transferable between containers. If it's not possible using the current standard library functions, the chances are it's not doable.

Comment: `alloca` and it's variants are non standard and should be avoided if at all possible but one can wrap it similarly. It's available on most compilers but it is NOT standard C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would rather the size be specified by the user using some similar
>   constructor setup to Vector's (ex. MyArrayClass myArray(10) ). How
>   might I try and implement this Array wrapper?

The purpose of `std::array`, unlike `std::vector`, is that the size is specified at compile time. Its underlying structure is a plain vanilla array which needs the size at compile time.

I can think of the following wrapper in case it is useful

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class Array {
  public:
    // stuff
  private:
    std::array<T, N> array_;
};
```